Vscode подчеркивает импорт
Такой импорт:
import type {
  Adapter,
  AdapterUser,
  VerificationToken,
  AdapterSession,
  AdapterAccount,
} from "next-auth/adapters"

из такой библиотеки:
node_modules/next-auth
├── adapters.d.ts
├── adapters.d.ts.map
├── adapters.js
├── client
├── core
├── css
├── index.d.ts
├── index.d.ts.map
├── index.js
├── jwt
├── LICENSE
├── middleware.d.ts
├── middleware.d.ts.map
├── middleware.js
├── next
├── package.json
├── providers
├── react
├── README.md
├── src
└── utils

подчеркивается такой ошибкой:
Cannot find module 'next-auth/adapters' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

но файл adapters.d.ts присутствует тут.
Как исправить это дело?

Попробуйте установить @types/next-auth и/или @types/next-auth/adapters (с аргументом -D)

Слишком мало вводной информации. Приложите пожалуйста tsconfig файл. У меня работает представленный вами импорт. Возможно, у вас "moduleResolution": "Classic"?

Дефолтный от nuxt

Опять-таки, выполнил у себя npx create-next-app@latest и npm i next-auth.  Импорт из вопроса распознается без ошибок. Проблема где-то на вашей стороне в конфигурации ts

я не пользуюсь next
